# Arqade Gamer IDs

Tags: discussion, community

Feel like playing games with your fellow Arqade members but don't know their contact information? Fear not! [Shotgun ninja](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/42129/shotgun-ninja) whipped up a [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AiGq12jWfs1ndFdBNXJLaVFnZlpudU1kTWIycWw3eVE) for just this purpose!

The [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AiGq12jWfs1ndFdBNXJLaVFnZlpudU1kTWIycWw3eVE) contains the username/friendcode/whatever for various gaming platforms (Steam, PSN, Desura, et cetera). So feel free to add in your own contact information if you want others to find it. If there's any platform not already there feel free to add it to the spreadsheet.

[Spreadsheet is located here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AiGq12jWfs1ndFdBNXJLaVFnZlpudU1kTWIycWw3eVE)

Comment: All I ask is that you please don't misuse the spreadsheet.

Comment: Come on, this is the internet! As if anyone would misuse anything...

Comment: ... Nice try, NSA...

Comment: Flagged as spam!!11!1 Also filled in my contact info.

Comment: [Everthing I know is a lie.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/carRT.png)

Comment: That file is an utter mess.

Comment: Also, can you link to the spreadsheet more visibly? Having trouble finding it.

Comment: Might be a good idea to include links to Steam profiles, since Steam names aren't inherently unique and Steam's friend search is fuzzy.

Comment: @kotekzot I agree, even though steam usernames are unique, (it's the display name that isn't)